# Making method shorter when adding properties

Tags: java, arrays, button

I have two arrays with button-objects:

```
this.rightButtons = new JButton[MAX_RBUTTONS];
this.wrongButtons = new JButton[MAX_WBUTTONS];
```

And I add properties (color, etc.) to each one of these by:

```
private void preferences(String buttonType, int num) {
    if (buttonType.equalsIgnoreCase("right")) {
        this.rightButtons[num] = new JButton("");
        this.rightButtons[num].setToolTipText("gg");
        this.rightButtons[num].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
        this.rightButtons[num].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        this.rightButtons[num].setOpaque(true);
        this.add(this.rightButtons[num]);                   
    } else if (buttonType.equalsIgnoreCase("wrong")) {
        this.wrongButtons[num] = new JButton("");
        this.wrongButtons[num].setToolTipText("gg");
        this.wrongButtons[num].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
        this.wrongButtons[num].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        this.wrongButtons[num].setOpaque(true);
        this.add(this.wrongButtons[num]);
    }
```

As you see, they have the same properties. Is there a way to change this code to a shorter one? The only thing that changes is `this.wrongButtons` and `this.rightButtons` (name of array).

Comment: You can obviously extract the button creation into an own method and use either `this.rightButtons[num] = createMyButton();` or `this.wrongButtons[num] = createMyButton();`. And if you like to change the tooltip (since it makes no sense to me to use the same for both cases), just pass the String to the `createMyButton` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just centralize the common part inside a method (and pass parameters for more flexibility) :

```
private JButton createButton(String tooltip, int width, int height, Color color){

        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setToolTipText(tooltip);
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));
        button.setBackground(color);
        button.setOpaque(true);

        return button;
    }
```

Then call it :

```
if (buttonType.equalsIgnoreCase("right")) {

    this.rightButtons[num] = createButton("Is this the correct one?",40,40,Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    this.add(this.rightButtons[num]);                   
} else if (buttonType.equalsIgnoreCase("wrong")) {
    this.wrongButtons[num] = createButton("Is this the correct one?",40,40,Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    this.add(this.wrongButtons[num]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's very simple - everything about the button is the same apart from where you're storing it. So create it, then store it:

```
private void preferences(String buttonType, int num) {
    JButton button = new JButton("");
    button.setToolTipText("gg");
    button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
    button.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY)
    button.setOpaque(true);
    add(button);
    JButton[] array = buttonType.equalsIgnoreCase("right")
        ? rightButtons : wrongButtons;
    array[num] = button;
}
```

(This assumes every button type is either "right" or "wrong".)

Personally I'd advise using lists instead of arrays, by the way...